# Automatically disconnect GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-api-client

I want to write a wrapper for `GoogleApiClient` to automatically disconnect during the activity's `onDestroy` method, if it is not explicitly closed. Main motivation for this is to avoid memory leaks by forgetting to call `disconnect()` on GoogleApiClient created using Activity context. I would like to use this wrapper throughout the application.

I wanted to know if there is any recommendation favoring or against this kind of a design decision to create auto-closing connections ?

Answer (score 4):

There is an answer provided but it is not the best solution, nor does it answer the question directly. The question was how to automatically manage GoogleApiClient. There is an option for this called `enableAutoManage()`.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder

You can enable this doing the following:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this) //auto manage disconnecting client
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

Additionally, onPause() is not the best place to disconnect your client. You should use onStop(). Especially now since is it guarenteed to be called post-Honeycomb devices (API 11 +)

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // stop GoogleApiClient
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just do: `

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Your application logic
    // ...
    // ...

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

as regularly and just **don't forget to include `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()` in there**, not on `onDestroy()` as this is not the lifecycle that Google implements (or at least tries to recommend, in your case), you still need to call the client connection on `onStart()`. This solution is just one line of code long